# Frontend to backend request seems to be wrong

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

Hi I am trying to deploy a simple React + Node app to a remote server. Backend started with pm2 and seems ok, frontend works with nginx, but when I try to get data from the db, console sends message

```
GET http://localhost:8080/v1/names net :: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED xhr.js: 177
```

Not too sure if I need to replace request url with the server IP instead of localhost.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should change all your request from localhost to your deployed address, I would also propose you take a look at .env Files to do it. [Node.js Everywhere with Environment Variables!](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786).

usually, you should use .env files to automatically choose the good address when deployed and when coding locally. have a nice day.

example of code with a .env file from the back with mongoose.

```js
mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.qvs4c.mongodb.net/${process.env.DB_NAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  )
  .then(() => {
    app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 5000);

    app.listen(app.get("port"), function () {
      console.log("Node app is running on port", app.get("port"));
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

example of my .env File.

```js
DB_USER=thatsmydbuser
DB_PASSWORD=thatsmypassword123!
DB_NAME=thatsmydbname
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Can you pls point how can i find default env variable name for request url?

Comment: check the link ;p. you create a .env and a .env.production file (if it's front and react) and you access the data from it Like that process.env.DB_USER for example. Please validate the resp.

Comment: and when you will be in prod(deployed) it will take the data from .env.production and when locally from the .env file automaticly.

Comment: I don't understand the question sorry.

Comment: Mate I'm using .env with dotenv. I am trying to find if I have a variable like DB_URL and then call it from db connection class like

"mongoose.connect (DB_URL, {
               useCreateIndex: true,
               useNewUrlParser: true,
               useUnifiedTopology: true
           });"

So if I add some variable for the request url like
REQ_URL=www.domain.com

Where in the code should i call it to replace path with localhost

Comment: you're connecting to the DB from the front?.

Comment: I added in my resp an example.